# Как подключиться к API Яндекс.Переводчика в своем Java-коде?

Tags: java, http, яндекс-переводчик

Не могу понять, как подключиться к API Yandex Translate в своем Java-коде.
[Документация API](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/translate/api-ref/Translation/translate).

Код, который я написал:

```
String key = "тут мой ключ";
String baseUrl = "https://translate.api.cloud.yandex.net/translate/v2/translate";
try {
    URL url = new URL(baseUrl);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", out.length + "");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
    connection.setRequestProperty("targetLanguageCode", lang);
    connection.setRequestProperty("texts", text);
    connection.setRequestProperty("folderId", "идентификатор папки");
    connection.getOutputStream().write(out);
    if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        jobj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
        JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jobj.get("text");
        // JSONArray jarr = (JSONArray)jobj.get("text").getAsJsonArray();
        return msg.get(0).toString();
    } else {
        return connection.getResponseMessage();
    }
```

Запрос возвращает:

> Bad Request

Comment: за код стыдно, да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понятно, что я разбирался в том, что совершенно не понимаю. Но теперь понял. Проблему решил: подтянул Apache HttpClient, закинул грамотно запрос и распарсил ответ.

```
final static String IAM_TOKEN = "/тут мой ключ/";
final static String folder_id = "/тут мой айди/";
...
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
String result = "";
try {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://translate.api.cloud.yandex.net/translate/v2/translate");
    String body = String.format("{\"targetLanguageCode\":\"%s\",\"texts\":\"%s\",\"folderId\":\"%s\"}", lang, text, folder_id);
    StringEntity params = new StringEntity(body, "UTF-8");
    params.setContentType("charset=UTF-8");
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    String auth = String.format("Bearer %s", IAM_TOKEN);
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.addHeader("Authorization", auth);
    request.setEntity(params);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        Object jsob_obj = new JSONParser().parse(retSrc);
        JSONObject json_res = (JSONObject) jsob_obj;
        JSONArray res_translate = (JSONArray) json_res.get("translations");
        JSONObject res_json_obj = (JSONObject) res_translate.get(0);
        result = (String) res_json_obj.get("text");
        System.out.println(res_translate);
    }
} catch (Exception ignored) {
} finally {
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```